# Avoid Splash Screen to launch when user open app from recent screen

Tags: java, android, android-activity, splash-screen, recent-screens

I wanna know how I can avoid splash screen to launch when my app is in recents.

I want the app to open the activity where user was in it before  when he/she  clicks back button of device and opens
app from recent screen.

This is a splash screen activity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
//variables
    private static int SPLASH_SCREEN = 1000;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);



        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this , Main_Page.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        },SPLASH_SCREEN);


    }
```

Comment: Whether or not a system-supplied splash screen appears on Android 12 is up to the OS, not you or I. If you are referring to some splash screen that you are showing manually, you need to handle whether or not to show that yourself.

Comment: can you add some code or details on how you are creating your splashScreen. is it an activity ?

Answer (score 0):

In the manifest, specify for the activity:

```
android:noHistory="true"
```

Comment: I did, but that did not work. splash screen 
 still appeares.

Comment: this will remove app from recents

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem.

This happens because when I click back button of device, according to

activity lifecycle , ondestroyview() will be called. so  when

I returned from recents screen , app started again.

what I've done is that in the next activity which appears after Splash

Screen , I used onBackPressed like this :

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
             moveTaskToBack(true);
         
    }
```